# How to move my headline box to the bottom of image

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I know it aint short but I fresh in css and I can't solve those questiones for about 2 weeks now...

I can't move my `.headline-box` to the bottom of the image. I'v tried to change my display and play with, block, flex, grid and changing it to row/column justify/align but nothing. I'v ried to change position to `bottom: 0` an squat...

Can any one pls tell how to fix it? And you this solution?

Why nothing that I'v done worked?

And why when I gave position: relative to this class, it went after the image, Down side..?

And besides that, I can really use help to make my code more simple...

I post link but this the url:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/pVpZRG)

Thank you all :)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: By the way, is this the reason the justify/ alignment didn't workd on grid an flex? And 3 more thing that I didnt understand...1. when I shrinking my browser to check the responsiv, the text go out of box. I think it because theres no more space. I'm right?  2. when I chenge things like font-size in my @media it's effects also out side the media..do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved your `.headline-box` to the bottom as you wished. The problem was caused by a few things, the most important one being that your header/container-fluid/row did not have a height, and because your body did not have a height either, doing this would give no result anyway.

I did the following things:

- `body` & `html` now has a height of `100%` (always do this!)
- `header` also has a height of `100%`.
- removed the image from your html and applied it as a `background-image` on your header.
- your `.headline-box` now has `bottom: 0`, which now puts it at the bottom.
- I cleaned up your code significantly and left out the following *unnecessary* items:

  - the extra `<section>` for just one `h3`.
  - `<div id="main img-div">` did not have an ending tag.
  - was also unnecessary because you already neatly put your content in a `header` and `section`(s).

Here is the updated [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/JvLXRZ).

If you have any further questions, please let me know :)

Comment: By the way, is this the reason the justify/ alignment didn't workd on grid an flex? And 3 more thing that I didnt understand...1. when I shrinking my browser to check the responsiv, the text go out of box. I think it because theres no more space. I'm right?  2. when I chenge things like font-size in my @media it's effects also out side the media..do you know why? 3. Still didn't understand why the text went out of image in .headline position: relative

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question about the grid. 1. Yes, you can resolve that by using media-queries. 2. That shouldn't happen, so it might be a mistake in your media-query. 3. Can you be more specific? Maybe with a picture?

If the answer answered your initial question, can you mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks :)

Comment: How do I mark it? Sorry I'm new here :) 3. When the image was in a tag and not as a background, and I gave to my .headline... relative instead of absolute, The txt went after the image, And in the same matter, Why did you move the image to a background image?

Comment: 3. No, you can put it back into the HTML as you want and apply the necessary styling to the image in your CSS, but in my opinion it is better practice to set background images in your CSS. This way it is much easier to control the size, such as `background-size: cover`. And little changes like putting the red border on the header instead of the image. The code is cleaner and allows for easier changes. - And thanks!

Comment: Mmm...after I checked it on my desktop, I realized that in this way, the image isn't full height.. Can I fix it in the way of your way? And If I wanted to apply that to img tag how could I do it ? this is my pen after I had couple of you changings and it doesn't get the bottom '0' and one more thing and I don't know Why, It's like when I scroll down, (in my pen - editor view) the box floats vertical until it's stuck in the middle :) kinda funny in a disturbing way...

Comment: Sorry, your comment is very unclear. Did you mean to send me a new codepen with an updated version?

Comment: No, I'll resend you my old/updated one : http://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/pVpZRG  I don't know why But I'm really cracking my head on the wall with this position thing

Comment: I found the issue. First of all you forgot a semicolon after `height` in your `#image` class. The issue is that the `.headline-box` has a position of absolute, so its height would be relative to its parent, but the parent div (.row) has no height, and the parent div of .row (.container-fluid) also has no height, and lastly, the parent div of .container-fluid (header) also has no height. [**> See this <**](https://i.imgur.com/otWX7Pa.png). To fix this, just give your `.row`, `.container-fluid` and `header` a height of 100%. (This is why I avoid using so many divs! haha)

Comment: Wow I did not know that... And I know your way is better, just want to get the rip of that. And in your way, how do I can make the image full height ? cause I tried couple of things and nada

Comment: Uhm... dude... Why when I did all that, and I'm shrinking my browser window vertically, the image shrinks too ?  hh And still be great to know how to fix it in may (the long) way and in yours

Comment: "And in your way, how do I can make the image full height?" For me it is full height. Can you show me with a screenshot what you mean? If you don't want the image to shrink, then don't use `background-size: cover` because that will make the image fit the whole screen, so also when the screen is very small.

Comment: Hi, know what, I'll make a new question, because the comments here make it messy. Still If You could answer it there I'll appreciate it very much!